# How get more info about these error like "Unspecified error" or "[object Object]"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, logging

On React Native log, i always get an error "Unspecified error" or "[object Object]". How get more info about these error?

NB : It's not my variable(and i want to find it). The goal is to know where it is.

Comment: can you please share more code where you are getting the error ?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know where is the error! What i want to track too

Comment: Do you have debugging tools? You can get it to pause on caught exceptions and then see what's happening and where. Also if you're logging objects, make sure you're not including text in that log, or you'll always just get that unhelpful [object Object]. So better to do `console.log(myObject)` rather than `console.log('Object = ' + myObject)` if that makes sense.

Comment: @James > what debugging tools should i use? it's not my variable, i don't know where is the variable, and the goal is to know that

Comment: I use this one: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger - it's pretty good for debugging redux and all source code - shows you what values variables have when you've paused, and you can pause on errors. To connect with Redux you need to add a couple of lines before you create your store. You'll use `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` instead of `compose` when you're in dev mode, so I've written it as `const composeEnhancers = __DEV__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose : compose;`. It's all in the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

`console.log(JSON.stringify(error))` this will provide error details.

Comment: thanks, but it's not my variable, i at the moment i don't know what cause it, and the goal is to know what is causing this

Answer (score 0):

Don't use + sign, use

```
console.log("error :" , objectWhichYouWantToDisplay)
```

- sign is used for appending strings. That's why you are getting this output on console.

Comment: thanks, but it's not my variable, i at the moment i don't know what cause it, and the goal is to know what is causing this